# Save Memory in Windows application

Tags: .net, memory

I have about 30 picture boxes in my form.
all pictures are the same.
how can i save memory in this case?
for example define a picture and bind it to all picture boxes.
to increase application size and Reduce memory usage.
thanks.

Comment: Why on earth do you have 30 PictureBoxes?

Comment: These are my games NUTS!.
i use a png picture as nut.
better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a single `Image` instance in your code and display the same instance in every PictureBox.

---

Writing a game with PictureBoxes for every sprite is an **extremely** bad idea.
You should draw your game by hand by handling the Paint event of a double-buffered control.

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6.aspx).

Comment: Call `new Bitmap(path)` or `Image.FromFile(path)`.

Comment: So.
I Designed My board and NUT  in photoshop and saved as PNG.
i am creating Backgammon.
I cant Design that nuts and board in .net .
how can i optimize?
what is correct way?

Comment: You should draw all of the PNG images manually in a single Paint event.